# I need to write text from a file to tkinter canvas - the error is bad screen distance

Tags: python, text-files, tkinter-canvas

I need to write a few lines from a file to the canvas. the error is bad screen distance. Can someone please help me?

```py
f = open(“mytus_fakt.txt”, “r”, encoding = “utf-8”)
for i,row in enumerate(f):
    x = row.split(“\t”)
canvas.create_text(x,y-750, text = x[0])
```

It should write the first couple of words (until tabulator) on tkinter canvas, but it is not working the error is bad screen distance.
How can the data from the file be drawn on the canvas?

Comment: `x` in `canvas.create_text(x,y-750, text = x[0])` is a list of string, not an integer of x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert both x and y to `int`s using `int(x), int(y)`
Here's an example usage:

```py
canvas.create_text(300, 50, text="HELLO WORLD", fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))
```